# Loop not iterating fully

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple RPG as a learning experience. In my code I have an array of tiles that are displaying on a 25x25 grid just fine, and a separate array that contains the True/False values pertaining to whether the tile is solid. The latter is not working; in my code below I have put a print statement exactly where it is not reaching, and i'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Also, the data for the level is simply a text file with a grid of 25x25 characters representing blocks.

```
def loadLevel(self, level):
    fyle = open("levels/" + level,'r')
    count = 0
    for lyne in fyle:
        if lyne.startswith("|"):
            dirs = lyne.split('|')
            self.north = dirs[1]
            self.south = dirs[2]
            self.east = dirs[3]
            self.west = dirs[4]
            continue

        for t in range(25):
            tempTile = Tiles.Tile()
            tempTile.value = lyne[t]
            tempTile.x = t
            tempTile.y = count
            self.levelData.append(tempTile)
        count += 1

    rowcount = 0
    colcount = 0

    for rows in fyle:
        print('Doesnt get here!')
        for col in rows:
            if col == 2:
                self.collisionLayer[rowcount][colcount] = False
            else:
                self.collisionLayer[rowcount][colcount] = True
            colcount += 1
            print(self.collisionLayer[rowcount[colcount]])
        if rows == 2:
            self.collisionLayer[rowcount][colcount] = False
        else:
            self.collisionLayer[rowcount][colcount] = True
        rowcount += 1

    print(self.collisionLayer)
```

Where exactly is the problem? I feel as though it is a quick fix but I'm simply not seeing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You read through the file once with your first `for` loop, so there isn't anything left to read for the second loop. Seek back to the beginning of the file before starting the second loop:

```
fyle.seek(0)
```

Although I'd just cache the lines as a list, if possible:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as handle:
    lines = list(handle)
```

Also, you can replace this:

```
if rows == 2:
    self.collisionLayer[rowcount][colcount] = False
else:
    self.collisionLayer[rowcount][colcount] = True
```

With:

```
self.collisionLayer[rowcount][colcount] = rows != 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop:

```
for lyne in fyle:
```

... reads all of `fyle` and leaves nothing to be read by the loop:

```
for rows in fyle:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to reopen the file. If I recall, python will just keep going from where you left off. If there is nothing left, it can't read anything. 
You can either re-open it, or use the fyle.seek(0) to go to the first character in the first line.